# Blank empty space on my website

Tags: html, css

I'm working as a trainee for a local business through school, and I'm having an issue with the website I've created. The problem is that there seems to be an empty space on the right of the website and at the bottom before the footer.

I've searched throughout the net for answers on this matter and have tried all sorts of methods as removing width: 100%; at every place I have them, I've tried deleting a lot of content step by step, in both html and css in order to figure out what's causing said problem,

I'll link my html & css if anyone can provide any help.

I have the root folder for the website inside here, so downloading the whole folder should give you an exact look at how it is.

```
 https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d4j89bvq594ilcm/AABYTOxlXYV1wbFvetYSM3pAa?dl=0
```

JSfiddle link for the index page, you can see the stretch to right & bottom

```
https://jsfiddle.net/dkrm6p2x/
```

Comment: Please provide your code or jsfiddle link

Comment: You have a minimum height set on the footer div,

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dkrm6p2x/ here is the code for the index page, and here you can see the page stretch to the right and empty space between content and footer. There's a slideshow on the page which doesn't show in the jsfiddle link.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your empty space comes from these two attributes:

```
.social {
  left: 1300px; }

#Footer {
  min-height: 600px; }
```

Remove them and the empty space is gone.

Comment: Such a simple answer! Have to remember checking for theese values in the future. Thank you, you saved me some time on my project!

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot, since I've now fixed all the other similar issues I was experiencing due to other faulty code, which came from similar mistakes!

Comment: You are most welcome! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of renaming the question title with "Solved", you can mark my answer as "accepted". Hope you'll find the site useful.